# npm install not making symlinks for local dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

As I understand it from the npm docs, `npm i /path/to/mylib` should normally create a symlink of `node_modules/mylib-> /path/to/mylib`. However when I run that `npm i` command above, npm will not create symlinks but actually create a copy of the package in `node_modules`. Despite that my `package.json` will read `"mylib" : "file:/path/to/mylib"`.

I want it to be a symlink since I am still working on the libraries I am adding in this project.

How can I make these symlinks?

- node version 16.15.0
- npm version 9.1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The change

This was a breaking change with npm v9. The release notes are available [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.0.0).

Including this detail on the option;

> `install-links` config defaults to "true"

In particular, there is this note in the release of node v18.4 [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V18.md#configcommand-deprecations-or-removals), motivating the change;

> Explanation: install-links is the only config or command in the list that has an effect on package installs. We fixed a number of issues that came up during prereleases with this change. It will also only be applied to new package trees created without a package-lock.json file. Any install with an existing lock file will not be changed.

In our use case, this broke the build and a change to the intended use of the functionality to begin with.

If set to `false`, then the "current/old/pre v9" behaviour is restored.

### Restoring the behaviour

Depending on the use case, there seem to be two options to consider;

- Add the option `--install-links=false` to the command line. Good for single use cases.
- Add the line `install-links=false` to the .npmrc file in the project root. Seems to be the better option for CI/CD environments.

*Note: the package-lock file format may have to be version 3 (or above) for the above to work.*

Comment: works perfect. Thanks. i burnt lot of time trying to figureout why it wasnt creating symlinks

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your use case you should probably just use `npm link`.

If you're working on an application and one of it's dependencies at the same time, you can use `npm link` to share the dependencies' project code inside your consuming application project.

It's a two step process:

1. `cd` into dependency folder (eg `~/code/calculation-sdk`) and run `npm link`
2. `cd` into your main folder (eg `~/code/payment-service`) and run `npm link calculation-sdk`

This will keep your code linked in both AND you still have the benefits of a clean `npm` based process.

If you want to clean everything up (eg delete the link), simply `npm uninstall` as you normally would.

Update - Here's a nice article - https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-use-npm-link-7375b6219557